# How do I get SHOP_SESSION_TOKEN from Big Commerce when making a Cordova HTTP request?

Tags: javascript, cordova, bigcommerce

I'm making the following call in Cordova to Big Commerce and trying to get the call to return a cookie named 'SHOP_SESSION_TOKEN':

```
cordovaHTTP.post('https://store-{store-hash}.mybigcommerce.com/remote.php', 
{
    w: 'expressCheckoutLogin', 
    login_email:'me@example.com', 
    login_pass:'xxxxxxxxxxx'
}, {}, 
function(response){},
function(response){});
```

I'm getting one cookie returned when I make the call in my code (not the one I want), but when I run the call in Postman, there are 42 cookies returned (including the one I want).

Just wondering what I need to add to my code to get this cookie returned.

Answer (score 1):

When you run the call in Postman (using Interceptor), it includes the cookies that **you already have present on your browser!**

If you clear your cookies from chrome, and then re-run the request in Postman, you will see that it only returns two cookies.

[image]

You can always get accurate response data via curl...

```
curl -c - -X POST https://store-hash.mybigcommerce.com/remote.php
```